# How can set Date in Request Headers in HttpHeaders in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, http-headers

I was tried to many ways to set Date in Request Headers in Angular, But its not taking Date in the http request.

I tested same thing in Postman and its working there, But not working in Angular.

I written below code for it

```
indiaPostBookingAPI(accessToken: any, bookingDeatil: any, indiaPostBookingUrl: any): Promise<any> {
    return await this.httpClient.post<any>(indiaPostBookingUrl + '/Booking/api/createbulkreq', bookingDeatil, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `${accessToken}`).set('x-request-id', "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000").set('Date', "Wed, 16 Oct 2019 07:28:00 GMT")        
    }).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean by "but not working in angular"

Comment: I am trying to set request header with Date : "Wed, 16 Oct 2019 07:28:00 GMT", And when i seen in google chrome in Networks, then Date is not adding in Request Headers, So how can add it